# Estimation of residual links: Calculate $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(3i)^k}{k!}}$

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem:**

Estimation of residual links.: Calculate $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(3i)^k}{k!}}$ except for an error of the amount $<10^{-4}$. How many row members do I need?

I guess I have to use:

**Theorem 8.15:**

Let $(a_k)_k$ be a monotonically decreasing null sequence (sequence tending to 0) in $\mathbb{R}$. Then there is a $z\in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z|\leq 1$ and $z\neq 1$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{a_kz^k}$ convergent and $$\bigg |\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}{a_kz^k} \bigg | \leq \frac{2a_n}{|z-1|}$$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $a_k = \frac{1}{k!}$. Unforyunately, $|3i|>1$, so this theorem doesn't seem useful in estimating $|\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k (3i)^k|$. You can however derive something similar, but specific to this case.

Note that if$k\ge n$ then
$$ |a_{k+1} (3i)^{k+1}| = \frac{3}{k+1} |a_{k} (3i)^k| \le \frac{3}{n+1} |a_{k} (3i)^k|$$
$$ |a_k (3i)^k| \le \left(\frac3{n+1}\right)^{k-n} |a_n (3i)^n|$$
$$ \sum_{k=n}^\infty |a_k (3i)^k| \le \sum_{k=n}^\infty \left(\frac3{n+1}\right)^{k-n} |a_n (3i)^n| $$
that means that for $n\ge 3$:
$$ \left| \sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k (3i)^k \right| \le\frac{1}{1-\frac{3}{n+1}} \frac{3^n}{n!}$$
You just need to find the $n\ge 3$ such that $$ \frac{1}{1-\frac{3}{n+1}} \frac{3^n}{n!} \le 10^{-4}$$
You can check that $n=14$ is enough.